# How to display image from image URl on a map in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Need an assist with a React app I am building. I use a map to show all properties of a document from Firestore. Here is my map:

```
    const getdata = Object.entries(myData)
    .map(pair => {
        const key = pair[0]
        const value = pair[1]
        return (
            <div className="card z-depth-2">
                <div className="card-content">
                    <div className="thisClass">
                    <h5>{key}</h5>
                    </div>
                    <p>{value}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    })
```

The value of some of the key: value pairs are photo URLs. I would like to check the map for the URLs and instead of displaying them in the p tag as strings, pass them inside img tag to show the actual image.

When I do an "if" check inside the map for the value, I get an error saying the string is null. Does anyone know how to do it?

Here is my if check:

```
        const key = pair[0]
        const value = pair[1]

        var someData = value
        var url = someData.slice(0, 4)
        if(url === 'https'){
            return(
                <img src={url} />
            )
        }else {

            return (
                <div className="card z-depth-2">
                    <div className="card-content">
                        <div className="handover-data">
                        <h5>{key}</h5>
                        </div>
                        <p>{value}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
```

I get an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of null

Thanks.

Comment: How are you using a if condition in map , can you add that code please? And also if possible the data

Comment: You should provide the data and the console logged output too.

Comment: I have added the error and the if condition